# Unable To Allocate Space

Tags: c, memory, stm32

Can someone help me to understand what exactly means this error message;

```
Error[Lp011]: section placement failed 
            unable to allocate space for sections/blocks with a total estimated minimum size of 0x1cc1c bytes (max align 0x4) in  
<[0x08000000-0x0801b7ff]> (total uncommitted space 0x1b740). 
Error while running Linker
```

I know it is about the running out of memory, but I don't understand how much memory.

Comment: The message says "a total estimated minimum size of 0x1cc1c bytes" (0x1cc1c is equal to 117788). You probably either have to many global variables, to large global variables (think large arrays), or to much code.

Comment: and `0x08000000-0x0801b7ff` is `1b800` bytes of space available, ie 112640 bytes. So you're 5148 above that limit. Or rather 1b740 bytes available, so you're 5340 bytes above.

Comment: @mmixLinus Please don't answer in comment, write a real answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the linker says, there is a `total uncommitted space 0x1b740` but your program uses `total estimated minimum size of 0x1cc1c bytes`.

`0x1b740` is 112448 bytes, and `0x1cc1c` is 117788 bytes, giving a difference of **5340 bytes.**

Your program is 5340 bytes over the limit.